# How do I add KtLint style to Android Studio using Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, ktlint

I want to add the style `ktlint` uses to Android Studio so that when I apply formatting myself it uses the `ktlint` style.

Based on the documentation, I installed the `ktlint` CLI

```
brew install ktlint
```

I then navigated to the root of my project and executed

```
ktlint --android applyToIDEAProject
```

The style now appears in my preferences for use.

The issue is that the style applied through CLI uses what I think is the latest version of `ktlint` since my manual formatting is different from the formatting `Gradle` task.I would prefer if it used the style from the `Gradle` plugin so the style applied to the project is the same one the `Gradle` task uses when formatting.

Finally, I would like it to be a Gradle task so that other developers can import and apply the same style as I could create a hook.

Below is my 'ktlint' Gradle file

```
dependencies {
    ktlint "com.pinterest:ktlint:0.34.2"
}


task ktlint(type: JavaExec, group: "verification") {
    description = "Check Kotlin code style."
    classpath = configurations.ktlint
    main = "com.pinterest.ktlint.Main"
    args "src/**/*.kt"
}

check.dependsOn ktlint

task ktlintFormat(type: JavaExec, group: "formatting") {
    description = "Fix Kotlin code style deviations."
    classpath = configurations.ktlint
    main = "com.pinterest.ktlint.Main"
    args "-F", "src/**/*.kt"
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

I looked into one of the Gradle plugins available and saw this file. To me it looks like a wrapper around the main library so it must be possible without using the 3rd party plugin. https://github.com/JLLeitschuh/ktlint-gradle/blob/master/plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/jlleitschuh/gradle/ktlint/KtlintApplyToIdeaTask.kt

The version I was using is 0.34.2 and comparing that to the latest, it looks like support for those commands were added later as seen here https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint/blob/master/ktlint/src/main/kotlin/com/pinterest/ktlint/Main.kt#L49

From this information, I have added this Gradle task which has progressed me but still fails.

```
task addKtLintStyle(type: JavaExec, group: "formatting") {
    description = "yep"
    classpath = configurations.ktlint
    main = "com.pinterest.ktlint.Main"
    args "--android", "applyToIDEA"
}
```

It fails with this error

```
.idea directory not found. Are you sure you are inside project root directory?
```

Which is thrown here

https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint/blob/master/ktlint/src/main/kotlin/com/pinterest/ktlint/internal/ApplyToIDEACommandHelper.kt#L27

My gradle file is in the root of my project so I am not sure what to do next at this point.

Comment: There are existing `ktlint` Gradle plugins: https://github.com/pinterest/ktlint#with-a-plugin---recommended

Comment: Check this step by step https://stackoverflow.com/a/74249501/6236959

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get this to work. This was the final task definition

```
task addKtLintStyle(type: JavaExec, group: "formatting") {
    description = "Adds The KtLint Style To Your IDE"
    classpath = configurations.ktlint
    main = "com.pinterest.ktlint.Main"
    args "--android", "applyToIDEA", "-y"
    //Point to the root directory because this task needs access to the .idea directory
    workingDir(getRootDir())
}
```

Note the line

```
    //Point to the root directory because this task needs access to the .idea directory
    workingDir(getRootDir())
```

and also

```
    args "--android", "applyToIDEA", "-y"
```

The `-y` just accepts the applied style.

After restarting Android Studio, I am able to see the `ktlint` style

Comment: Even after doing this, I couldn't get the Android Studio formatter to behave the exact same as ktlint

Comment: @dazza5000 I had the same issue too. I have a git hook that runs ktlint on push and I noticed it formats the ktlint formatted code again. Decided to not use the ktlint style for the moment.

Comment: Yea - you need to go all in. You can install the unofficial ktlint plugin or use the command line. Those are your most reliable options.